# Override Auth Forgot Password in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am using built in laravel auth functionality.Its working fine.I am trying to override following two functionality.

1.send forgot password email using mandrill.

2.send verification email while registering account.

Can any one help me to solve this issue

My aim is to use mandril instead of default email

I can see auth built in methods but i didnt got idea how i can override that

```
trait ResetsPasswords
{
    use RedirectsUsers;

    /**
     * Display the password reset view for the given token.
     *
     * If no token is present, display the link request form.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  string|null  $token
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function showResetForm(Request $request, $token = null)
    {
        return view('auth.passwords.reset')->with(
            ['token' => $token, 'email' => $request->email]
        );
    }

    /**
     * Reset the given user's password.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function reset(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, $this->rules(), $this->validationErrorMessages());

        // Here we will attempt to reset the user's password. If it is successful we
        // will update the password on an actual user model and persist it to the
        // database. Otherwise we will parse the error and return the response.
        $response = $this->broker()->reset(
            $this->credentials($request), function ($user, $password) {
                $this->resetPassword($user, $password);
            }
        );

        // If the password was successfully reset, we will redirect the user back to
        // the application's home authenticated view. If there is an error we can
        // redirect them back to where they came from with their error message.
        return $response == Password::PASSWORD_RESET
                    ? $this->sendResetResponse($response)
                    : $this->sendResetFailedResponse($request, $response);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

As answered by Mahfuzal, Laravel comes with a bunch of mail drivers out of the box. So just update your `.env` file to use the right driver.

As for sending a verification email when creating an account, you just need to override the `postRegister()` function inside the `Auth/AuthController` like so:

```
public function postRegister(Request $request)
    {

        $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $this->throwValidationException(
                $request, $validator
            );
        }

        $confirmation_code = str_random(30);
        $newUser = new User;
        $newUser->username = $request->username;
        $newUser->email = $request->email;
        $newUser->password = bcrypt($request->password);
        $newUser->confirmation_code = $confirmation_code;

        $newUser->save();

        $data = array('confirmation_code' => $confirmation_code, 'username' => $request->username);

        Mail::send('emails.verify', $data, function ($message) use ($newUser){
            $message->to($newUser->email, $newUser->username);
                $message->subject('Please verify your email address');
        });

        return redirect('/auth/login');
    }
```

This will execute the above code when registering a user rather than what Laravel does default out of the box so just tweak it to your needs.

You then just need to create a function that will check the token and verify their account when they click the link. For that, I use something similar to what is explained [here](http://bensmith.io/email-verification-with-laravel).

Comment: @James.Thanks.i have already changed 'driver' => 'mandrill' and i am getting following error Passing in the "body" request option as an array to send a POST request has been deprecated. Please use the "form_params" request option to send a application/x-www-form-urlencoded request, or a the "multipart" request option to send a multipart/form-data request.

Comment: @iCoders https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/l5-mandrill-error

Comment: @james.how to fix that issue.

Comment: @iCoders have you tried either of the solutions suggested in that link?

Answer (score 1):

> Laravel provides drivers for SMTP, Mailgun, **Mandrill**, Amazon SES,
>   PHP's mail function, and sendmail, allowing you to quickly get started
>   sending mail through a local or cloud based service of your choice.

Open your `.env` file and change following by your Mandrill credentials and then you're good to go.

> MAIL_DRIVER=mandrill
>
> MAIL_HOST=
>
> MAIL_PORT=2525
>
> MAIL_USERNAME=null
>
> MAIL_PASSWORD=null
>
> MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

Comment: .Thanks.Ya.i also saw in mail.php config file.how to send email verifcation when registration and modify template

Comment: if i change to mandrill i got following error.Passing in the "body" request option as an array to send a POST request has been deprecated. Please use the "form_params" request option to send a application/x-www-form-urlencoded request, or a the "multipart" request option to send a multipart/form-data request.

Comment: Oh! This is due to a depreciation issue in GuzzleHttp. Check here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/l5-mandrill-error

Comment: how to fix that issue

Comment: Add this `"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.0"` in your  `composer.json`, and then run a composer update. Hope downgrading version will fix that.

Comment: ya.thay=t we can do is there any fix issue for latest version of guzzle.i have "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.3|~6.0",

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own `reset` method in the controller that uses the trait to override the method in the trait.